# Regex text after words

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am working with php and I am trying to make regex get everything after a certain line (a part of a Dig response).

This is the data I am working with.

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> @ns2.msft.net microsoft.com a +comments +noquestion +noauthority +noadditional +nostats +nocmd
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 10742
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; ANSWER SECTION:
microsoft.com.      3600    IN  A   134.170.188.221
microsoft.com.      3600    IN  A   134.170.185.46
```

I just wish to get the two last lines and nothing else (sometimes there are more or less).
This almost does what I want, but it only checks for the last : and some responses has a : in the very last line (TXT records).

```
[^:]+$
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^[^;]*
```

I guess this simple regex should do it for you.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/rK5lU1/33

```
$re = "/^[^;]*/im";
$str = "; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> @ns2.msft.net microsoft.com a +comments +noquestion +noauthority +noadditional +nostats +nocmd\n; (1 server found)\n;; global options: +cmd\n;; Got answer:\n;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 10742\n;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0\n;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available\n\n;; ANSWER SECTION:\nmicrosoft.com. 3600 IN A 134.170.188.221\nmicrosoft.com. 3600 IN A 134.170.185.46";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: Wow that was incredibly easy! I think I have tried almost everything else! :D

Comment: Hmm. Actually it seems that PHP does not like the g in /gim. I get an error preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'g'

Comment: very close now. Only problem is that it now returns more than needed. I just wanted it to return the last lines (and nothing if it isnt found)

Comment: It returns a multidimentional array. In [0][0] i get the ; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> @ns......

Comment: @Resin01 use `^[^;\n]+`

Comment: Perfect. That did it. It now works even better than before! Thanks